# Removing a todoItem from the list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am sorry for asking this, since I think this has been asked before. However I do not understand react enough, or at all to understand the answers people have given on other questions. Neither to implement them into the code I have.

this is the main code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import TodoItem from './components/TodoItem';

class App extends React.Component {

componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({todoList: [], inputField: ''});
}

handleInput(event) {
    this.setState({inputField: event.target.value});
}

addTodo(event) {

    if(this.state.inputField.length === 0 || event.keyCode && event.keyCode !== 13) return;

    event.preventDefault();
    var newTodo = {
        text: this.state.inputField,
        created_at: new Date(),
        done: false
    };
    var todos = this.state.todoList;
    todos.push(newTodo);
    this.setState({todoList: todos, inputField: ''});
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {
                    this.state.todoList.map(function(todo, index){
                        return (
                            <TodoItem todo={todo} key={index} />
                        );
                    })
                }
            </ul>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="newTodo">Add Todo item</label>
                <input name="newTodo" value={this.state.inputField} type="text" onKeyUp={this.addTodo.bind(this)} onChange={this.handleInput.bind(this)} />
                <button type="button" onClick={this.addTodo.bind(this)} >Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(
        <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and this is the other part:

```
import React from 'react';

class TodoItem extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {todo: props.todo};
}
toggleDone(event) {
    var currentTodo = this.state.todo;
    if (currentTodo.done) {
        currentTodo.done = false;
    } else {
        currentTodo.done = true;
    }
    this.setState({todo: currentTodo});
}

removeTodo(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var todos =  this.state.todoList;
    todos.remove(this);
}

render() {
    return (
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.toggleDone.bind(this)} />
            <span className={this.state.todo.done ? 'done' : ''} >
            {this.state.todo.text}</span>
            <button type="button" onClick={this.removeTodo.bind(this)} 
            >X</button>
        </li>
    );
  }
}

export default TodoItem;
```

Firstly I had the remove function in the main code, but I got an uncaught type error than because  it couldn't find the bind??

And when I put it in the second part of code, I get a cannot read property "remove" of undefined error.

Any help would be awesome!
Thx upfront

Comment: *"I get a cannot read property "remove" of undefined error."* The state of `TodoItem` doesn't have an entry `todoList`. It only has `todo`. `todoList` is part of the state of `App`. I'd recommend to go through the React tutorial to learn the basics: https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html .

Comment: Yeah I looked at the tutorial and it the code written for that tic-tac-toe game didnt help me at all. I tried changing my code, but I now get errors saying that something.remove is not a function.

Comment: I get the Idea of props and classes and states in react now. But I dont think I need the values of the objects but the entire object to be removed which I did not learn in the tutorial. They used .slice, but I tried that before I tried .remove and you need the index of the array for that to work. Which I dont know how to get so I still dont get any of it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **removeTodo** function from **TodoItem** component and put it in **App** component. Pass this function as prop to **TodoItem** component and call this function at cross button click. Remember, bind **removeTodo** function to App component after moving it.

Comment: Thank you!!! you are my hero, If I could I would appoint you as president, since you are such great of an individual!